# Multible JQuery load Function without Class

Tags: jquery

I am newbie and get to no solution maybe someone can help me please.

Normaly i change a Div content dynamic by using Load an a click function with prevent default and classes.

It looks like this:

Java / Jquery

```
 $('.call').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $('#main').load(this.href);
 });
```

HTML

```
 <li><a href="start.php" class="call">Start</a></li>
 <li><a href="start2.php" class="call">Start2</a></li>
 <li><a href="start2.php" class="call">Start2</a></li>
```

and so on ...

Now i need the Class to set it to "Active" when it is active so i cant use it any more in this way ...

Ids dosent Work the are Unique so i cant give all links the same ID and i dont want to write for every Link a Function.

Thanks !!!

Comment: why wouldn't it work when you add a class to it using the `.addClass()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work when you use the `addClass()` function from jQuery in this manner:

```
$('.call').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('#main').load(this.href);
 });
```

A JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xXCZc/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class and remove all other classes so you can't click it anymore:

```
$('.call').click(function (e) {
    var that = $(this);
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#main').load(this.href, function() {
        that.removeClass().addClass("active").off(); //off will remove the handler.
    });
});
```

Comment: If you assign `click` handler this way, it will continue to handle clicks, even if you remove `call` class.